# test driven asynch tasks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am looking for general thoughts and/or links on the topic in general, although my specific motivation at the moment are UI tasks related to progress reporting using either BackgroundWorker and / or TPL. My experience level with async programming in general is novice. The testing tools I know best are NUnit and Rhino.

Some brain storming ideas off the top of my head:

1. Don't bother - it's too complicated and you just wind up testing the BGW or TPL.
2. Make some sort of fake or mock.
3. Use EventWaitHandles

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Maybe post some code so we can see how your code is structured and answer accordingly...

Comment: @BFree. Yes, the question is touchy feely and therefore maybe too vague, but any of the code I have now wouldn't lend itself to a short post or a quick answer. If the question was about starting to use mocks, for example, maybe someone would suggest Rhino along with the wiki and maybe a good blog post about getting started with it along with some tips from their own experience. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unit testing asynchronous code is not the simplest thing in the world, as I learned when writing unit tests for my [Nito.Async](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/) library. :)

First, you want to define what you actually want to test. Do you just want to test whether the asynchronous action is performed, or do you want to ensure that your BGW/tasks are properly synchronizing their UI progress reporting?

Testing the action is pretty straightforward: just wait until the action is complete and then check for postconditions. (However, be aware that the BGW `RunWorkerCompleted` will be raised on a `ThreadPool` thread unless you give it a synchronization context like the example below).

Testing proper synchronization (e.g., that each piece of code is running on the correct thread) is more complex.

For each test you'll need to establish a synchronization context. This will be mocking the UI synchronization context. My Nito.Async library may help with that; it has an `ActionThread` which is a separate thread that contains a synchronization context suitable for owning EAP components (e.g., BGW) and scheduling tasks (e.g., `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`).

It can be used like this (using an MSTest example):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  using (ActionThread thread = new ActionThread())
  {
    thread.Start();

    // Anything passed to Do is executed in that ActionThread.
    thread.Do(() =>
    {
      // Create BGW or call TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext.
    });

    // The thread is gracefully exited at the end of the using block.
  }
}
```

I find `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` to be the easiest ways to check for proper synchronization. If your test code is run from within `ActionThread.Do`, then it should synchronize its progress updates (and completion notification) to that `ActionThread`.

A lot of the Nito.Async unit tests use `ActionThread` in this manner, so you could look there for various examples.

Comment: Now *that's* what I'm talkin' bout! I assume you wrote this to make async life easier and there isn't a real alternative. Are your tests included with the download? How well must one know TPL to understand your code? Am looking at your blog now. Cheers

Comment: Looking at your ProgressReporter code on your blog, for example, and how that might be tested without needing to make a win forms or other ui project. Great stuff!!

Comment: The library was originally written to assist with writing EAP components. However, note that the future directions of VS (as indicated by the VS Async CTP) introduces TAP which will (I hope) replace EAP. So some parts of Nito.Async will no longer apply in just a few years. It still has several useful components, though, such as `ActionThread`. The class has two purposes: allow Console/Windows Service programs to have a synchronization context; and to make my unit tests easier to write. :)

Comment: The unit tests are included in the source. Nito.Async does not currently make use of any of the TPL. The TPL was quite well designed and there's less need of a "fill in the gaps" kind of library like what Nito.Async was for the pre-.NET 4.0 days.

Comment: P.S. EAP = [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkasytyf.aspx); TAP = Task-based Asynchronous Pattern.